# Random Aframe environment

Tags: javascript, random, aframe

I want to have random scenarios every time I enter the website.
So I'm trying to return the ***pickscenario*** variable from the js script to aframe in this line `<a-entity environment="preset: pickscenario"></a-entity>`

Here's the code:

```
<a-entity environment="preset: pickscenario"></a-entity>
        <script>
             var scenarios = ['ocean', 'universe', 'forest'];
             var pickscenario = scenarios[Math.floor(Math.random()*scenarios.length)];
             return pickscenario;
        </script>
```

I bet this is quite simple but I haven't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For scripts to take effect it is advised to write components, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
AFRAME.registerComponent('randomscenario', {
   init: function(){
       var scenarios = ['ocean', 'universe', 'forest'];
       var pickscenario = scenarios[Math.floor(Math.random()*scenarios.length)];
       this.el.setAttribute('environment', { preset: pickscenario});
   }
});
</script>
```

And then in the html:

```
<a-entity randomscenario></a-entity>
```

The init function is called when the scene is loaded.